# Prevent Logged Out users from the entire website

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

i'm working on an admin website that i've built using React and firebase and i want the whole site to be accessible only to those who are logged in. I want to do it from one place though as opposed to having to add it to every page which is what this requires:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(!user) {
    window.location = 'login.html'; //If User is not logged in, redirect to login page
  }
});
```

I am thinking of the `app.js` page but i'm having problems. Here is my attempt:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const setLoggedInFn = () => {
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
  };

  const setLoggedOutFn = () => {
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn === false) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn, navigate]);

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation setLoggedIn={setLoggedInFn} setLoggedOut={setLoggedOutFn} />
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
          <Route path="/page2" element={<Page />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

But i get the following error:

> useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a  component.

I understand the error but i want to know if its possible to do it in one place like app.js

FYI, navigation is in every page so i decided that that's where i should monitor the logged in state.
A section of `Navigation.js`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
      auth,
      (user) => {
        // console.log(user);
        if (user) {
          setUserId(user.uid);
          setIsLoggedInFn();
        } else {
          setUserId("");
          setIsLoggedOutFn();
        }
      },
      []
    );

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

Is there a way to block the entire site from one place?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best if you check if it is not logged then just preview the Login component without navigating.
This is how you can achieve it:

```
import {Login} from "./path/to/login/component"
export default function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState();

  const setLoggedInFn = () => {
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
  };

  const setLoggedOutFn = () => {
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoggedIn?(
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation setLoggedIn={setLoggedInFn} setLoggedOut={setLoggedOutFn} />
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
          <Route path="/page2" element={<Page />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
     ):(
       <Login/>
     )}
    </>
  );
}
```

NOTE: Don't forget to change the Login component path to the correct path.
I hope it helps